# http post request curl

Tags: http, curl, http-post, httprequest

I have this website where I make a http post request
http://requestmaker.com/

My question is how can I make this request with curl or other similar command line apps? windows or linux doesnt matter.

My Request URL is something like this:

```
http://www.website.net/servers?server%5Bgame%5D=cstrike1&server%5Bdomain%5D=192.168.1.1&server%5Bport%5D=27000
```

Request Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Refer: http://www.website.net/servers/new
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) yet?

Comment: yes but not the whole thing, i'm not a pro with these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" -H "Refer: http://www.website.net/servers/new" "http://www.website.net/servers?server%5Bgame%5D=cstrike1&server%5Bdomain%5D=192.168.1.1&server%5Bport%5D=27000"
```

but I think you meant to set the `Referer` header instead of `Refer` and you should probably POST JSON data since the `Content-Type` is `application/json`.

Comment: Don't forget `-d` for the actual JSON data being posted. You can also use `-A` for the user agent, and `-e` for the referrer, instead of using `-H` manually.  You should also not send `Accept-Encoding` manually unless you are prepared to decode compressed response data yourself, otherwise use `--compressed` instead and let curl handle it.

Comment: yes I meant Referer and another mistake was Content-Type it should be Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded but It's not working.

Comment: then you should probably use `-d "server[game]=cstrike1&server[domain]=192.168.1.1&server[port]=27000"` which POSTs those parameters instead of passing them as query parameters in a GET